# Overlay a card partially on an image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to partially overlay a `Card` on an image using `Stack`, just like this

[image: Example]

So this is what I have tried

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/placeholder.jpg"),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              ),  // image
              new Positioned(
                  child: Card(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('1625 Main Street',
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          subtitle: Text('My City, CA 99984'),
                          leading: Icon(
                            Icons.restaurant_menu,
                            color: Colors.blue[500],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ) //card
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

However it displays the card at the bottom of the image but trying to overlap it partially over the image with the help of Stack's `bottom`, `top` arguments makes the card not display all together. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that when you're making your stack, you're not allowing it to size itself properly. A stack sizes itself to any children which are not positioned - in your case, the ClipRRect. The ClipRRect looks like it is sized to its child image, which has a defined height. So the stack will also be this size I believe (you can turn on debug painting to see).

It looks like you want the image and white to be the background for your entire page, which means that you should be letting the stack expand to the size of the page. Wrapping your image in an alignment should do this.

The next part is that you've made your card positioned, but not defined any parameters. You want to define at the least the top, but probably also the left and right.

This works for me (although I'm not using all the same widgets, but it should apply anyways):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Card over stack"),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)), color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 60,
              right: 10,
              left: 10,
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('1625 Main Street', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                  subtitle: Text('My City, CA 99984'),
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.restaurant_menu,
                    color: Colors.blue[500],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```